# Dúvida lógica do código em PHP

Tags: php, html, if, for

Olá, pessoal. Estou iniciando no PHP e estou tendo algumas problemas com este código:

```
<?php

    function linha($semana) {

        echo "<tr>";
                for ($i= 0; $i <= 6; $i++) { 
                        if (isset($semana[$i])) {
                            echo "<td>{$semana[$i]}</td>";
                        } else {

                            echo "<td></td>";
                        }
                    }   

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    function calendario() {

        $dia = 1;
        $semana = array();
        while ($dia <= 31) {
            array_push($semana, $dia);

            if (count($semana) == 7) {
                linha($semana);
                $semana = array();
            }

        $dia++; 
    }

    linha($semana);

    }

?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Domingo</th>
        <th>Segunda</th>
        <th>Terça</th>
        <th>Quarta</th>
        <th>Quinta</th>
        <th>Sexta</th>
        <th>Sábado</th> 
    </tr>
    <?php calendario();?>
</table>
```

Como é possível perceber, ele resulta em um calendário (sem especificidades). Eu não consigo entender a lógica deste código. Por que usar o for? Pra que usar o if?

Se alguém puder me ajudar com a lógica deste código eu agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse calendário em si, é inútil. Ele apenas incrementa um contador sem obedecer qualquer variável que um calendário possui. Mas vejamos:

```
<?php 

function calendario() {

    // Define o primeiro dia como 1
    $dia = 1;

    // Define que $semana será uma variável do tipo array
    $semana = array();

    // Inicia um loop até o que seria o dia 31, desobedecendo quaisquer eventuais regras do calendário. Nem todos os meses possuem 31 dias
    while ($dia <= 31) {

        // Adiciona o valor do dia dentro do array $semana
        array_push($semana, $dia);

        // Verifica se a variável $semana possui 7 elementos
        if (count($semana) == 7) {

            // chama a função linha() e passa a variável $semana como parâmetro
            linha($semana);

            // Zera o array $semana
            $semana = array();
        }

        // incrementa +1 no valor de $dia
        $dia++; 
    }

    linha($semana);

}
```

A função abaixo apenas itera pelo array que foi passado como parâmetro e cria uma nova linha na tabela com os 7 elementos (números, considerados como dias no calendário)

```
function linha($semana) {

    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i= 0; $i <= 6; $i++) { 
        // verifica se possui o elemento na posição $i do array $semana
        // Caso possua, imprime o valor na tela
        if (isset($semana[$i])) {
            echo "<td>{$semana[$i]}</td>";
        } else {

            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }   

    echo "</tr>";
}


?>
```

Comment: Obrigada, Marcelo! Estou treinando minha lógica e este problema estava um pouco difícil de entender, mas sua explicação ajudou muito!